# application to restore/download all market applications after new rom is installed

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, custom-roms, factory-reset

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to recover apps from a factory reset?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/20143/how-to-recover-apps-from-a-factory-reset)

the AndyX Rom has a wonderful feature that grabs all applications previously installed from the market once you do all wipes and new rom setup.

[ONLINE AndyX ROM™ v6.0 - XXLPH - Samsung Galaxy S II I9100 | forum.xda-developers.com](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1460702)

unfortunately any other custom rom I used does not have this feature so I have to go to the market again and download all app one by one like skype, whatsapp and so on.

is there an app that would work on all the roms which I could use to grab all what I had installed before regardless in which rom I installed the apps? Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [AppBrain](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.appspot.swisscodemonkeys.apps) to sync the list of your apps to the service, flash, reinstall AppBrain and sync your device again to reinstall your apps.

The only downside is that when you resync your device you have to accept every app install separately. Or at least this was the case when I last used it (ages ago).

Comment: That is not the case if you enable Fast Web Install (separate app from same developers).

Comment: Is it just me or the link gives 404?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a backup application (I use [My Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rerware.android.MyBackup) myself, requires root access). Actually, Google has some kind of backup and in case you reinstall your ROM or something goes wrong, it immediately download all the apps you had before from Google Play Store (at least it does so for me).

Answer (score 1):

[Titanium Backup](http://market.android.com/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup) can do this.  You'd just want to be careful to only do a restore of non-system apps, as your new custom roms apps are likely to have data incompatibilities.