# Automatically Install apps after factory reset

Tags: applications, samsung-galaxy-s-2, installation

I'd like to know how I can set up my android 4.1.2 (Galaxy S2 I 9100) that it will install all my apps in the Play Store (the one you can see when you click "my apps"). 
I think it was CM 10.1 where it worked sometimes and in stock rom I did not noticed it. 
Is there a way to configure my Galaxy S2 so I don't have to install the apps manually? 
I hope I asked clearly enough ;) 
Thanks so far !

Edit: I reseted my phone, logged into samsung account to google account. 
I always allowed to back up and restore my data. But the apps haven't been installed automatically. 
And that was the only thing I tried. I did not try any ADB recoveries. And I did not use any backup third party apps or the stock rom backup. 
I hope this information is enough. I fnot please tell me what information you additionally need! 
Thank you again!

Comment: Rather similar: [How to recover apps from a factory reset?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/20143/how-to-recover-apps-from-a-factory-reset)

Comment: Does not work :( And I searched for "reinstall", "install after reset" but I did not guess to search "recover" ... :D

Comment: What "does not work"? The Backup/restore via ADB described there, or the Google backup? I'd recommend you update your question with some more details, to enable us to help you.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you have checked Automatic Restore and Backup my Data in Settings>Backup & Restore.

And also sync your google account right after a reset. You'll notice that all of your apps are reinstalling in the background.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

I guess it has to do with what you had on your device installed right before
you wipe & flashed a new Rom.

Google remembers last apps and all