# Android device manager - remote erase phone's data

Tags: samsung

I'm accidentally press the remote erase, and my phone memory and SD card memory data has gone. is there any way to restore my erased data?

Comment: Look into the resources under [tag:data-recovery] tag in that case. These may help too: [How can I recover a deleted file on Android?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/15869) || [How to recover apps from a factory reset?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/20143)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but you've remotely performed a factory reset on your phone. The only data that can be recovered is that which you've manually backed up off the device (to PC or cloud) or has been backed up automatically.